# Access TextView string resource name programmatically

Tags: android, textview, android-resources

I have a TextView created in xml e.g.

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/hello_world_text_view"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

and my **strings.xml** file has the property

```
<string name="hello_world">Hello World!!!</string>
```

Is there any way to get programmatically the resource name (in my example "hello_world") from the TextView?

Comment: `R.string.hello_world` ? Or do you mean to fetch the `@string/hello_world` from code? if latter, then no.

Comment: String string = getString(R.string.hello);

Comment: `getResources.getString(R.string.helloe_world);`

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Comment: Yes but I want to take the resource name programmatically e.g.
Text View t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hello_world_text_view); 
String resourceName = ??

Comment: @Shark Yes I meant get the {@string/hello_world} from code.

Comment: `getResources().getIdentifier("text_name","id",getActivity().getPackageName()));` try this to get the R reference

Answer (score 0):

You can do programatically like this

```
TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.hello_world_text_view);

getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.id.hello_world_text_view);
```

Comment: It's incorrect. Using this you will get something like hello_world_text_view

Answer (score 0):

Use this way

```
String packageName = "your package name";
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(YourString, "string", packageName);
textView.setText(getString(resId));
```

Comment: `getIdentifier(....)` expect first parameter to be the `name` of resource instead of resource value. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Answer (score -1):

```
TextView txt_hello = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello_world_text_view);
```

get your text :

```
String hello = txt_hello.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
String yourValue = t.getText().toString();
int resourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier(yourValue, "string", this.getPackageName());
String resourceName = this.getResources().getResourceEntryName(resourceId);
```

Comment: resourceId == 0 in all cases.